# How to have multiple button groups with active toggle buttons

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I am working on a shopping page project and am currently using bootstrap buttons with button groups.
One group is for size and the other is for color.
I need to be able to select a button for the size of the product.
And select a button for the color of the product.
my problem is that bootstrap untoggles the first button group when I click off of the buttons or on the second button group for the color. please help and let me know if there are any needed clarifications.

Comment: Not bootstrap does untoggle ... the browser untoggles (changes active state to other group) if you select other group. That is anchored in the browser system. I assume for this you need another solution maybe done in JS ... Are you able to post a code example? What is not clear to me: you select to items on a shopping page ... normally that should be two different select fields ... not two button groups ... so maybe you like to change code in form to select fields or maybe to two radio/opitions groups.

Comment: @Brebber for my design purposes select field will not work so I was thinking about switching to radio or check box groups, which will allow me to have one active button per group?

Comment: Not `active` ... state `active` is by system only able on one element on the page ... that's allways the element the user has clicked as long he does not click on another element. You need to select an option. If not a select field ... maybe an option/radio group does work as they hold the selection when you click on another element. I don't know if Bootstrap prepares a design ... but you are able to do nice things if use/design the labels of `inputes type=radio/checkboxes`.

Comment: Tipp: if you move the original radio element out of the window you are able to design allone and clicking on the label works as well ... Important: that are just rough ideas ...